# Django Model for mandatory/excatly one cross table relations

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to find guidance on how to build a model representing the following:

- We have IT environments (consisting of multiple components, like webservers, databases, etc.)
- SLAs are not specific to one environment, it's more a set of general contracts a concrete environment references to (aka should be a separate table)
- each environment must have at least one or more SLA(s) associated
- From all SLAs associated to an environment exactly one must have the state "effective"

I implemented a model sufficiently reflecting the first two points (at least, I think so), but especially the last point seems to be cumbersome.

Sufficiently meaning, using this implementation, the relation using the cross table is *optional*, not mandatory. This is OK currently, but not in the long run.

```
class Environment(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    ...
    sla = models.ManyToManyField(SLA, through='EnvironmentSLA')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('fullname', 'projectid', 'regionid', 'account'),)


class SLA(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reaction_time = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    service_level = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class EnvironmentSLA(models.Model):
    PLANNED = 'pl'
    EFFECTIVE = 'ef'
    DEPRECATED = 'dp'
    SLA_STATE = (
        ( PLANNED, 'planned' ),
        ( EFFECTIVE, 'effective'),
        ( DEPRECATED, 'deprecated'),
    )
    environment = models.ForeignKey('Environment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sla = models.ForeignKey(SLA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SLA_STATE, default=PLANNED)
```

So my questions are:

- Am I generally on the right track, but capturing the last constraint is not possible solely focusing on the model?
- What would be an elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a save() method for the model EnvironmentSLA that does the following:

1. check if the object to be saved set state == EFFECTIVE

   1. if not just save the object
2. try to get currently effective SLA
3. change the state SLA of the currently effective SLA to DEPRECATED
4. save the object

The save()-function looks like this:

```
class EnvironmentSLA(models.Model):
    [...]
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.state != self.EFFECTIVE:
            super(EnvironmentSLA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            return
        try:
            effective_sla = EnvironmentSLA.objects.filter(environment=self.environment, state=self.EFFECTIVE).get()
        except Exception as e:
            effective_sla = None
        if effective_sla:
            effective_sla.state = self.DEPRECATED
            effective_sla.save()
        super(EnvironmentSLA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way we don't loose the defined SLAs but always have only one active SLA.